# How to configure Python with lighttpd and fastcgi?

Tags: python, fastcgi, lighttpd

How to configure Python with lighttpd and fastcgi ? Can anybody give me config files ?

Comment: Google your **exact** question title and click on some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [serverconfig](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/pycopia/WWW/serverconfig.py) module can set that up. But it's made to work with a particular framework.